# How to link two Angular components through $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have some problem with Angular components:

Example:
**myApp.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            template: '<login></login>'
        })
        .when('/users', {
            template: '<users></users>'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
});
```

In my project I have "main" component that contain ng-view.

**main.js**

```
angular.module('remoteGuiApp')
.component('main', {
    controller: function ($location, $window, $http) {
        //some code here
        //...
    },
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
});
```

**main.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <!-- ome navigation code-->
</nav>
<div ng-view>
</div>
```

Also I have "login" component
**login.js**

```
angular.module('remoteGuiApp')
.component('login', {
    controller: function () {
        //some code here
        //...
    },
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
});
```

So I need somehow connect events from "login" component to "main" component.
Technically "login" is nested of "main", but it nested not directly but from $routeProvider. Maybe someone know how to do it? Thank's for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between AngularJS controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)

Comment: Controller and Component is very different Essence, besides I know how connect them but not through $routeProvider. Please read my question)

Comment: I've read your question. Each component contains a controller. The route provider has no effect on your issue, you can just forget about it for this case.

Comment: Otherwise, you can also use $rootScope.emit();

Comment: In componets scope is always isolate.

Comment: When the router switches views, it destroys the old component and its controller and removes it from the DOM. It then builds the new component and its controller and adds it to the DOM. Any data that needs to persist between different views needs to be stored elsewhere. Use a service to do that. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$rootScope.$emit](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/#rootscopeemitbroadcast). Of course you have to inject it, and then like this, in child:

```
$rootScope.$emit('rootScope:authenticated', userData);
```

And in parent:

```
$rootScope.$on('rootScope:authenticated', function (event, userData) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(userData));
  })
```